# Sending mail in asp.net using Exchange Server(smtp-outlook.office365.com)

Tags: asp.net, email, outlook, exchange-server, office365

We are working in Mailing system in asp.net,our client using Microsoft exchange server  outlook.office365. We are getting this exception.

> "System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: The operation has timed out " error .Please help us.

```
btn_click(){
try{SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient("smtp.outlook.office365.com");                             
                smtp.Host = "outlook.office365.com";
                smtp.Port = System.Convert.ToInt32("443");            
                System.Net.NetworkCredential cred = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("userid", "mypwd");
                smtp.Credentials = cred;            
                smtp.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
                smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
                smtp.EnableSsl = true;
                smtp.TargetName = "STARTTLS/outlook.office365.com";
                MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
                msg.From = new MailAddress("frommailid", "username");
                msg.To.Add(new MailAddress("xxx@xxx.com"));            
                msg.Subject = "Test";
                msg.Body = "Test mail ";
                smtp.Timeout = 60000;
                smtp.Send(msg);
}catch(exception ex)
{
throw ex;
}
}
```

Comment: Please share your code so we can investigate the problem?

Comment: please check above code..

Comment: try using the port 587 instead of 443 and update us if that worked

Comment: if it didn't work use {smtp.office365.com} instead of {smtp.outlook.office365.com}

Comment: "smtp.office365.com" is not working-- time out error

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  I have edited your post, I marked down your error using >.

Answer (score 0):

Refer the below code snippet and try this out. It worked for me.

> **Remember**: From field should be same email id which is used as an SMTP user. So in this example, **xxx@blabla.onmicrosoft.com** should be the From email id.

```
MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
mail.To.Add(new MailAddress(ToField.Text));
mail.From = new MailAddress(FromField.Text); //From field should be same email id which is used as a SMTP user.
mail.Subject = "Email Subject";
mail.Body = "Message Body";

SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("xxx@blabla.onmicrosoft.com", "Password");
client.Port = 587;//You can use Port 25 if 587 is blocked
client.Host = "smtp.office365.com";
client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
client.EnableSsl = true;
client.TargetName = "STARTTLS/smtp.office365.com";

try {
    client.Send(mail);
} 
catch (Exception ex) {
    ResponseLabel.Text = "Error:" + ex.Message;
}
```